# git destroyed my changes

Tags: git, github

I made a commit of my repository a week ago but never actually pushed it to the remote at github, which I did today. However, in the time from my commit I made many changes to the source. But just the initial commit was pushed to remote and while doing it, it also overwrote my local files.

What can I do to get back my current files??

For better understanding, this is what I've done:

1. Created new VS project and created a new git repository in it,
2. Performed an initial scan, stage and commit but without adding a remote and performing a push,
3. Worked on files for a week,
4. (Today) Forgot to perform rescan, new stage and commit and just created new GitHub repository and performed this:

git remote add origin git@github.com:myaccount/webshop.git

git push origin master

5. Now the files in GitHub repository are the ones from inital commit and those were also copied over my current files, so I'm in the initial commit stage now locally too, which is awful.

Help appreciated

Comment: Git doesn't do that. Push doesn't change the local uncommitted files, ever, so you must have made something else as well, perhaps a `checkout`?

Comment: nope, these two command is all i did

Comment: @mare: Are you saying that the one command `git push origin master` destroyed your local changes?

Comment: After running this command, Visual Studio immediately issued a wellknown warning, when files are changed outside of VS, saying that the project has changed and if I want to reload. I reloaded the project and the files were all changed. I was able to undo the files back but only the ones I had open. The ones that were not opened before were overwritten making me unable to revert back.

Comment: Maybe a checkout was performed under the covers? Is there something to undo the last checkout or push? I'm almost a complete beginner in git but so far I managed to get along fine.

Comment: Well, whatever happened, git isn't going to help you recover your files. Git can only provide what you have previously committed, and since you only have your single week-old commit, that's all it has to give.

Comment: Take a look at `git branch`, see if you haven't mistakenly committed into a different branch. If you have worked only for a week then I assume you don't have terribly many commits. Take a look at `git reflog` and together with `git show` try to fish out your missing commits. If you committed changes, they're there and you've got nothing to worry about. All you need is to find them in the reflog and rearrange the "wires" so things point to each other in the linear (or hierarchical) manner you wish. You may find `git grep`, `git rev-parse` and others useful in your crusade.

Comment: There was nothing else than git bash in action here. No manual files copying, nothing else. This is just insane if it so. From what I can understand here, it took everything from the initial commit and copied it over the new and updated files. And you are saying I cannot undo that? Let me also say that so far I have not performed any other action with git so the status is still as of that push.

Comment: @wilhemtell: there were no additional commits after the initial commit. I just went into visualize and there's just the initial commit.

Comment: For instance, I have a database MDF file which in my initial commit had 1 table, during the week I added 2 more tables (those changes were never commited or pushed anywhere), today I perfomed a push (without commiting the changes, so it obvious that the initial commit was pushed) and it also overwrote the files, so at the moment the MDF file has the initial 1 table again.

Comment: @wilhemtell: git reflog: e8ad7e6 HEAD@{0}: commit (initial): initial commit

Comment: @mare push doesn't change your work-tree. It doesn't. Look elsewhere.

Comment: @mare and that's it? only one commit in the reflog? And I understand you're looking for one more commit?

Comment: Only one commit in the reflog and that's fine. Only one commit was ever performed. It is just that the time between this one and only commit and a push of this commit was one week. And in the meantime I made changes to those files. These changes are now gone.
I don't know where else to look, those are files deep down my project folder tree and noone else touched them. ;)

Comment: Allright, I just went into GIT Extensions, opened the repo, and there's a thing called [stash] at the top of the tree. If I go into it (diff) there are files that I changed and the changes are displayed with green. Those green (+) lines should be made permanent now. There are also some binary files (like the forementioned MDF) for which it says this: "Binary files a/Web/App_Data/WebshopDatastore.mdf and b/Web/App_Data/WebshopDatastore.mdf differ"

Comment: Please log a bug on the git mailing list. There's no way that push should ever overwrite your working tree even if you had somehow made a repository its own origin. Data loss bugs are taken very seriously by the git developers.

Comment: Try `git stash list`, if that works and your status is clean (i.e. you have no further work to lose) try `git stash apply`.

Comment: well, `git stash apply` does change the working tree, so this is one command you need to be careful with.

Comment: @mare ah, so you stashed changes! well then, you're in luck. if you have any changes now commit them or stash them. Then `git stash apply` your old stashed changes. As @Charles said, you can list the stashes; this way you can say to `stash apply` which stash to apply, by ID.

Comment: $ git stash apply
Cannot apply to a dirty working tree, please stage your changes

Comment: $ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: e8ad7e6 initial commit

Comment: Try `git add -u` and then `git stash apply`. It should try to merge your stashed changes with the changes you have made locally since you stashed.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I've resolved it using git add -u and git stash apply and then done a few manual merge conflict resolutions in GIT Extensions. Apparently the changes were there in the stash all the time although I have no idea how they got there. Post those steps as the answer and I will accept it. Really appreciate your effort, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you accidentally stashed your changes.

This command lists any stashes that you have made.

```
git stash list
```

git will only apply a stash if you don't have any unstaged changes in your working tree, so to apply the changes you can stage any unstaged changes with this command.

```
git add -u
```

Then you can apply the stash with this command.

```
git stash apply
```

git may prompt you to resolve any conflicts if you are applying onto a file which has changed since you made the stash.